# CPU for desktop/server

Tags: cpu

Which is the difference between a server and a desktop CPU ? Why should I buy a Xeon processor for a server why don't use instead a simple Intel quad 4-core CPU for a desktop PC ?

Comment: Same question as http://superuser.com/questions/454398/are-there-seperate-processors-for-servers/454405#454405 - see my answer there.

Answer (score 3):

The Xeon processors are designed to work in multi-processor environments.  It is not unusual for a high end server to have two or four processors, each of which may have multiple cores.  A desktop processor, in contrast, typically must work alone.  If you are in need of a server for the home, there is nothing wrong with using a Core 2 Duo or Core 2 Quad processor (or their AMD counterparts).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=627972

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Links sometimes expire, thus making your answer useless. You can include most important parts of the linked site in your answer, then provide a link to the detailed article.